# TextInputLayout :How to set padding or margin to setError() of textinputlayout?

Tags: android, user-interface, androiddesignsupport, android-textinputlayout

I have to use TextInputLayout of Android design support library on my work. I would like to take the setError()'s text just under the EditText nearly, which located in TextInputLayout. Now is too far as the below image shown.

I set margin and padding in TextInputLayout but both are not work so I rollback my code with only setting android:layout_marginStart and android:layout_marginEnd.

Thanks for any suggestion.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_et_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColorHint="#B32F874E"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/til_et_ID"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:ems="12"
        android:textColor="#2F874E"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: SetError() is too far with EditText field]

Comment: You have a `layout_marginBottom` of `50dp` on the `EditText`. That's pushing the error text down. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @Mike M oic......You are right, SIR. Thanks for help.